# Codeigniter - custom callback not working (Database)

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, callback

When a user goes to settings to change his/her email, username, first name, etc, it validates if the email hes trying to change to already exists in the database, if it does, then he can't save the changes. However, by default, the `is_unique` only checks if the value exists in database, not if the value exists AND belongs to the user. For example, if the user is changing his information, and he doesn't change his email but changes his name and stuff, he cannot change it because it's going to say "Email already exists in database".

But I made a call_back function to check if the email has been changed or not.

It's not working, however.

My controllers: save, and call_back controllers:

```
public function save() {

    $uid = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //Initial checks: mistakes to look out for. For eg. username too long, etc.
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|max_length[20]|xss_clean|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|max_length[20]|xss_clean|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|max_length[20]|callback__is_unique_username[username]|xss_clean|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|valid_email|callback__is_unique_email[email]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('_is_unique_email', '%s already exists');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //user didn't validate, send back to login form and show errors

    } else {

        //successful update

        if ($result) {
            //do something
        } else {
           //do something
        }
    }
}

//----FUNCTION TO CHECK IF EMAIL IS ALREADY IN DATABASE WHEN USER UPDATES----/

public function _is_unique_email($value, $field)
{

    $result = $this->db->where('uid !=', $this->session->userdata('uid'))
        ->where($field, $value)
        ->get('users')
        ->row_array();

    if ($result) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_is_unique_email', 'The %s already exists in database.');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
//check if username is unique
public function _is_unique_username($value, $field)
{

    $result = $this->db->where('uid !=', $this->session->userdata('uid'))
        ->where($field, $value)
        ->get('users')
        ->row_array();

    if ($result) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_is_unique_username', 'The %s already exists in database.');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your `_is_unique_username($value, $field)` method takes in 2 parameters, I am wondering how when you pass in 'email' like `callback__is_unique_email[email]` where your variables come from?

Comment: Please refer to this answer as this is where I got it from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28868309/3720039

Comment: Nice, what was the fix?

Answer (score 0):

This may help You..

**Validation Rule:**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|max_length[20]|callback_is_unique_username|xss_clean|alpha_numeric');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|valid_email|callback_is_unique_email|xss_clean');
```

**Call Back Function:**

```
public function is_unique_email($email)
{

    $result = $this->db->where('uid !=', $this->session->userdata('uid'))
        ->where('email_address', $email) // Column Name to be checked
        ->get('users');


    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique_email', 'The %s already exists in database.');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```