# How to validate if name and email exists in MYSQL and check EDIT FORM if user cancelled to change the value using jQuery, AJAX, CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

When i try to change value on edit form and then i decide to cancelled the changes, i have an alert message that my previous value is exist in database.

How to fix this?

Initial state :

[image]

Then i want to change the **name** (nama) value :

[image]

Before i click **submit** (simpan), i decide to cancelled the changes and make it to the initial value (**admin**) :

[image]

Then i have an alert message that my **name** (nama) is exist in database. And This also applies to **email** case.

View :

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal fade" role="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Ubah Kasir</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="#" id="editform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Nama</label>&nbsp;<span class="error" id="report3"></span>
                            <input type="text" id="editnama" name="nama" class="form-control" maxlength="100" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>E-mail</label>&nbsp;<span class="error" id="report5"></span>
                            <input type="email" id="editemail" name="email" class="form-control" maxlength="150" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Kategori</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="kategoripetugas" id="editkategori" required>
                                <option value=""> -- Pilih Kategori -- </option>
                                <option value="1">Admin</option>
                                <option value="2">Kasir</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="editsubmit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;">Simpan</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller :

```
public function cekData($table, $field, $data)
{
    $match = $this->Crud->read($table, array($field=>$data), null, null);
    if($match->num_rows() > 0){
        $report = 2;
    }else{
        $report = 1;
    }
    echo $report;
}

public function register_email_exists()
{
    if (array_key_exists('email',$_POST)) {
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        if ($this->Crud->email_exists($email) == TRUE ) {
            echo false;
        } else {
            echo true;
        }
    }
}

public function getData($id)
{
    $query = $this->Crud->read('petugas', array('idpetugas'=>$id), null, null);
    foreach($query->result() as $result){
        $data = array('nama'=>$result->nama, 'email'=>$result->email, 'kategori'=>$result->kategori);
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data); 

}

public function updatePetugas($id)
{
    $nama_petugas = $this->input->post('nama');
    $email_petugas = $this->input->post('email');
    $kategori_petugas = $this->input->post('kategoripetugas');
    $data = array('nama'=>$nama_petugas, 'email'=>$email_petugas, 'kategori'=>$kategori_petugas);
    $update = $this->Crud->update(array('idpetugas'=>$id), 'petugas', $data);
    if($update){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 2;
    }
}
```

jQuery AJAX :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var check1=0; var id;
$("#nama").bind("keyup change", function(){
    var nama = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'kasir/cekData/petugas/nama/'+nama,
        data:{send:true},
        success:function(data){
            if(data==1){
                $("#report1").text("");
                check1=1;
            }else{
                $("#report1").text("*nama petugas sudah terpakai");
                check1=0;
            }
        }
    });
});

var check3=0;
var oldeditnama=$("#editnama").val(); 
$("#editnama").bind("keyup change", function(){
    var editnama = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'kasir/cekData/petugas/nama/'+editnama,
        type: "POST",
        data:{send:true},
        success:function(data){
            if(data==1){
                $("#report3").text("");
                check3=1;
            }else{
                if (oldeditnama==editnama){
                    $("#report3").text("");
                    check3=1;
                }else{
                    $("#report3").text("*nama petugas sudah terpakai");
                    check3=0; 
                }
            }
        }
    }); return false;
});

var check2=0;
$("#email").bind("keyup change", function(){
    var email = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'kasir/register_email_exists',
        type:"POST",
        data:{send:true, email:email},
        success:function(data){
            if(data==1){
                $("#report2").text("");
                check2=1;
            }else{
                $("#report2").text("*email sudah terpakai");
                check2=0;
            }
        }
    });
});

var check5=0; 
var oldeditemail=$("#editemail").val(); 
$("#editemail").bind("keyup change", function(){
    var editemail = $(this).val(); alert(oldeditemail);
    $.ajax({
        url:'kasir/register_email_exists',
        type:"POST",
        data:{send:true, email:email},
        success:function(data){ 
            if(data==1){
                $("#report5").text("");
                check5=1;
            }else{
                if (oldeditemail==editemail){
                    $("#report5").text("");
                    check5=1;
                }else{
                    $("#report5").text("*email sudah terpakai");
                    check5=0; 
                }
            }
        }
    }); return false; 
});

$(".edit").click(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url:'kasir/getData/'+id,
        data:{send:true},
        success:function(data){
            $("#editnama").val(data['nama']);
            $("#editemail").val(data['email']);
            $("#editkategori").val(data['kategori']);   
        }
    });
});

var check4=0;
$("#confirmpassword").bind("keyup change", function(){
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var confirmpassword = $(this).val();

    if (password == confirmpassword){
        $("#report4").text("");
        check4=1;
    }else{
        $("#report4").text("*Password tidak sama");
        check4=0;
    }
});

$("#submit").click(function(event){
    if(check1==0){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(check4==0){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(check2==0){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$("#editsubmit").click(function(event){
    if(check3==0){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(check5==0){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$("#editform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url:'kasir/updatePetugas/'+id,
        data:formData,
        type:'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            $("#editModal").hide();
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });

});
});
```

Comment: Show us the kasir/cekData/petugas/nama controller function..

Comment: See this question.. You will find solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867841/codeigniter-update-email-only-if-the-email-doesnt-exist-in-the-database

Comment: you can see **kasir/cekData/petugas/nama** at Controller above... **cekData** is function on Class **Kasir**, **petugas** it table's name and **nama** is field's name